# Trouble with validation after registration

Tags: php, mysql

I'm doing a registration page. It requires the name, password, email, gender, nationality, date of birth and other things.

I did the registration and it was good. But I need to add the validation and this is what I could do so far:

```
<?php include("config.php"); ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 

    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/validation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
                    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
                        dateFormat:'dd/mm/yy',
                        changeMonth: true,
                        changeYear: true,
                        yearRange: '-90:+0',
                        maxDate: '+0'
                    });
        });
    </script>
    </head>

    <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css" media="all">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css" type="text/css" media="all">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-yui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-replace.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Myriad_Pro_italic_600.font.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Myriad_Pro_italic_400.font.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Myriad_Pro_400.font.js"></script>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://info.template-help.com/files/ie6_warning/ie6_script_other.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <?php $error_messages = array(
        'T1' => 'Please enter a Name to proceed.',
        'T2' => 'Please enter a valid Email Address to continue.',
        'T3' => 'Please enter your Message to continue.'
    ); 
    ?>
    </head>
    <body id="page2">
    <div class="body1">
        <div class="main">
    <!-- header -->
            <header>
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <h1><a href="index.html" id="logo">Air Lines</a><span id="slogan">International Travel</span></h1>
                    <div class="right">
                        <nav>
                            <ul id="top_nav">
                                <li><a href="index.html"><img src="images/img1.gif" alt=""></a></li>
                                <li><a href="index-4.html"><img src="images/img2.gif" alt=""></a></li>
                                <li class="bg_none"><a href="#"><img src="images/img3.gif" alt=""></a></li>





                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                        <nav>
                            <ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                                <li  id="menu_active" ><a href="LSU.php">Login/sign up</a></li>
                                <li><a href="V&M.php">Vision and mission</a></li>

                                <li><a href="contact.php">Contacts</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <div id="banner"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- header -->
    <div class="main">
    <!-- content -->
        <section id="content">
            <article class="col1">
                <div class="pad_1">
                    <h2>Login</h2>
                  <form id="form_1" action="login.php" method="post">

                        <div class="wrapper">
                            User Name:
                            <div class="bg"><input type="text" name="LogIn_Name" class="input input1" value="Enter your name" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Enter your name'" onfocus="if(this.value =='Enter your name' ) this.value=''"></div>
                        </div>
                    <div class="wrapper">
                            Password:
                            <div class="bg"><input type="password" name="LogIn_Pass" class="input input1" value="Enter your password" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Enter your password'" onfocus="if(this.value =='Enter your password' ) this.value=''"></div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="wrapper">

                        <h2 id="coq"> <a href="Forget.php">Forget Password</a></h2>

                          <input type="submit" class="button2" value="GO">
                    </div>
                    </form>



                    <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
                </div>
            </article>
            <article class="col2 pad_left1">
                <h2>Registration</h2>
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <figure class="left marg_right1"></figure>
                    <p> 

                                    <form id="form_1" action="" method="post">
    <div class="wrapperr"  >
    <?php 

    $username =  $_POST["T1"];
    $password =  $_POST["T2"];
    $repassword =  $_POST["T3"];
    $email =  $_POST["T4"];
    $gender =  $_POST["T5"];
    $Cou =  $_POST["T6"];
    $DO=  $_POST["T7"];
    $passport=  $_POST["T8"];
    $phone=  $_POST["T9"];

    {
    if((strlen($username)<3)){
    echo "The username is too short"."</br>";


    if((strlen($gender)<3)){
    echo "Gender"."</br>";
    }


    if((strlen($Cou)<2)){
    echo "The CO too short"."</br>";
    }


    if((strlen($phone)<5)){
    echo "The phone is too short"."</br>";
    }

    if((strlen($password)<5)){
    echo "The password is too short"."</br>";
    }
    }
    else{
    if($password == $repassword){
    $chec = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM register WHERE name='$username'"); 
    if(strlen($chec['name'])>0){
    echo "The username '$username' already exists";
    }
    else{
    $check_variable=stripos($email,"@");
    if($check_variable){

    $password=md5($password);
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO register (name,password,email,gender,country,DOB,phone,passport) VALUES ('$username','$password','$email','$gender','$Cou','$DO','$phone','$passport')");
    echo "Registration Successful .. Click <a href='index.php'> here </a> to home";
    }
    else{
    echo "email is invalid";
    }
    }
    }
    else{
    echo "The password in both field doesn't match.";
    }
    }
    }






    ?>
        </div>              <div class="wrapper">
                            Name:
                            <div class="bg"><input type="text" name="T1" class="input input1"  value="Enter your name" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Enter your name'" onfocus="if(this.value =='Enter your name' ) this.value=''"></div>
                        </div>

                                            <div class="wrapper">
                            Password:
                            <div class="bg"><input type="password" name="T2"  class="input input1" value="Enter the password" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Enter the password'" onfocus="if(this.value =='Enter the password' ) this.value=''"></div>
                        </div>


                                            <div class="wrapper">
                            Confirm password:
                            <div class="bg"><input type="password" name="T3" class="input input1" value="Confirm the password" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Confirm the password'" onfocus="if(this.value =='Confirm the password' ) this.value=''"></div>
                        </div>

                                            <div class="wrapper">
                            e-mail:
                            <div class="bg"><input type="text" name = "T4" class="input input1" value="Enter your e-mail" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Enter your e-mail'" onfocus="if(this.value =='Enter your e-mail' ) this.value=''"></div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="wrapper">
                            Gender:
                            <div class="bg">
                              <td>
                              <input type="radio" name="T5" value="Male">
                              Male
                              </td><td>
                               <input type="radio" name="T5" value="Female">
                              Female</td>


                          </div>
                        </div>


                                    <div class="wrapper">
                            NATIONALITY:
                              <div class="bg"><input type="text" name="T6" class="input input1" value="Enter your country" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Enter your country'" onfocus="if(this.value =='Enter your country' ) this.value=''"></div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="wrapper">

                                                        <div class="wrapper">
                            Passport number:
                              <div class="bg"><input type="text" name="T8" class="input input1" value="Enter your passport number" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Enter your passport number'" onfocus="if(this.value =='Enter your passport number' ) this.value=''"></div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="wrapper">


                            Date of birth:
                      <div class="wrapper">
                                <div class="bg left"><input type="text" name="T7" class="input input2" value="mm/dd/yyyy " onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='mm/dd/yyyy '" onfocus="if(this.value =='mm/dd/yyyy ' ) this.value=''" id="datepicker"  >
                                  <br/><span id="bdayInfo"></span>

                        </div>
                                <div class="bg right"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        Phone number:
                                                <div class="wrapper">
                                <div class="bg left"><input type="text" name="T9" class="input input2" value="" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value=''" onfocus="if(this.value =='' ) this.value=''"></div>
                                <div class="bg right"></div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="wrapper">
                        <p>&nbsp;</p>
                      <input type="submit" class="button2" name="Go" value="GO">
                        </div>
                    </form>

                    </p>
                </div>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
              <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
            </article>
        </section>
    <!-- / content -->
    </div>
    <div class="body2">
        <div class="main">
    <!--footer -->
            <footer>
                Website template designed by <a href="http://www.templatemonster.com/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">www.templatemonster.com</a><br>
                3D Models provided by <a href="http://www.templates.com/product/3d-models/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">www.templates.com</a>
            </footer>
    <!-- / footer -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript"> Cufon.now(); </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What's the issue here? Besides having a huge chunk of PHP in the middle of a view blarghhsdfjs

Comment: Take a look here jQuery validation: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Answer (score 0):

Always validate server side first i.e. in PHP (this is the point where it **is required**).

Then add JavaScript validation afterwards. It **is not required**, but added to improve user expecrience.  Any javascript can be circumnavigated (avoided) so if you don't have the PHP backup then you're leaving your self open for trouble.

Note, I'm not saying don't add JS validation, merely that you add PHP first, JS second. Sometimes you find libraries / frameworks that can add both at the same time.

---

So back to your code: the error appears to be that you're checking for errors **after** you display the error. So it's going to fail.

Restructure your code as follows:

- Create default values for your form
- Create blank errors array.
- If POSTED, then read in values (over defaults), validate them
- If all is good, then process the form and redirect [`header('location: '); exit();`] to a results / thank-you page.
- (Note that at this point you have not outputted any HTML at all, merely updated your default values and error array)
- If all is not good (or you never got a post) then now show the HTML. You have default values for the inputs (will alos contain the POSTED values, if applicable) and error messages to display at the right points.

Basically, handle the data first, output last.

Once that is working, then ass jQuery validation (as suggested in comments). It's pretty good.

Answer (score -1):

HTML 5 has a bunch of built in validation tools and you could use jQuery or Javascript to further enhance that.  I am not a big fan of validating variables on a new page, especially when we could prevent the page load completely.  Definitely look into some sort of Client Side validation instead of posting to the the PHP page.

W3Schools has a decent article on Javascript validation:  http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp

The jQuery link was already given in a comment above.

If Javascript is not your specialty then try something like this.  It is prebuilt and has some nice features.  Best of all it is free.
http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml